# Renderizado de vistas con Twig

Tags: php, twig

Subí mi proyecto a un hosting compartido gratuito. No me renderiza las vistas como debería ser, es decir, todo me carga bien pero no muestra contenido, sólo aparece la página en blanco.
Probé colocando una página php con html convencional y todo funciona bien.

PD: De manera local utilizo un virtual host y todo me funciona bien.

```
declare(strict_types = 1);
namespace app\core\librarys;
use app\core\helpers\FunctionsTwig;
```

```
class View
{
    public static function create(string $path,  array $params=null){
        //Convertir el string recibido en array
        $path = explode('.',$path);
        $route = null;
        /*Crear mediante ciclo el formato ruta del archivo requerido*/
```

`for ($i=0; $i < count($path); $i++){
        if ($i == count($path)-1){
            /*Si es el ultimo se le anexa la extencion del archivo*/
            $route.=$path[$i].'.twig';
        }else{
            /*Mientras se sigue formando la ruta*/
            $route.=$path[$i].'/';
        }
    }
    /* Comprobar si la ruta obtenida del archivo es verdadera */
    if (file_exists(VIEWS_PATH.'templates/'.$route)){
        /* Se le establece donde estaran las vistas */
        $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(VIEWS_PATH.'templates/');
        /* Se le configuran opciones */
        $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader,[
            'cache'=> VIEWS_PATH.'cache/'
        ]);


        /* Agregar variables globales */
        add_twig_global($twig, array(
            'URL_ASSETS'    =>      URL_BASE.'public/assets/',
            'URL_TS'        =>      URL_BASE.'public/typescript/output/src/'
        ));
        /* Extension para poder crear funciones personalizadas */
        $twig->addExtension(new FunctionsTwig());

        if (is_null($params))echo $twig->render($route);else echo $twig->render($route, $params);

    }else{
        die('No existe el archivo');
    }
}`

}

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el código como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: Hice lo mejor que pude, la verdad nunca había formulado una pregunta por acá

Comment: Ya nos dirán los que conocen más de PHP / Twig si necesitan más información o no. Para próximas preguntas ten en cuenta que no es necesario adornar el texto con saludos y expresiones ajenas al problema en cuestión.

Comment: Gracias, lo tendŕe en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta desactivando la cache de Twig, si haciendo eso funciona quizás el problema sea que no existe el directorio o no tienes permisos de escritura.

Comment: Tampoco funciona viejo, ya probé. Y sí, efectivamente, en el hosting no me crea la carpeta para la cache; localmente sí.